# How to install iphone sdk 4 on Mac OSX 10.5.8

Tags: iphone, ios4

I found following sentence in the Xcode 3.2.3 Readme (Posted: August 11, 2010 in iPhone Developer Center) -

"Xcode 3.2 requires an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard version **10.6.4** or later."

But my develop environment is 10.5.8 and don't plan to upgrade my system currently. How to install the latest **Xcode 3.2.3 and iOS SDK 4.0.2** provided by Apple?

Did someone ever succeed to install the latest dmg on leopard instead of snow leopard? and how?

Thanks in advance.

Email/MSN: linkou.bian@gmail.com

Comment: another 'don't want to upgrade' question.. the problem is apple doesn't care whether we want their fancy upgrades.. you'll have to upgrade at some point.. so better do it now.. i haven't heard of anyone who has been able to do what you asked for.. yet..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to bite the bullet. The fact of the matter is that the later SDKs depend on features that are only available in 10.6 and not 10.5.

Even if you get it to install on 10.5 that's only the first hurdle. After that you might not even be able to get it to run, or it won't work properly or it will crash,. etc. etc. etc.

Apple move very quickly, and they don't look backwards, it's something you'll have to get used to.

Comment: Thanks. According to your suggestion, I plan to install 10.6 on this weekend.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so simple to upgrade your system. Not like everyone has a couple grand laying around all the time. Plus when your married, it's hard to justify spending 2k on a new computer when your current one works just fine for  everything except deploying webapps as iphone apps.

I would try this. I am currently downloading it now. We'll see how it goes.

http://www.dropthenerd.com/iphone-sdk-3-1-3-download-for-leopard-if-you-dont-have-snow-leopard/

I HAD SUCCESS!!

All you have to do after installing the sdk is make sure you move two files:

1) move /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform     to  /Developers/Platform/iPhoneOS.platform
2) move /Platforms/IphoneSimulator.platform    to /Developers/Platform/IphoneSimulator.platform

if you don't want to copy those two 3gig files you can make symbolic links using the terminal

ex. 
sudo ln -s /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform /Developers/Platform/iPhoneOS.platform

and the same for the other one.

After this you can also install things like phoneGap

Here is further documentation

http://forums.ilounge.com/iphone/223546-how-iphone-sdk-ppc-mac.html

Comment: Why do you have to spend 2k? A new MBA or Mac mini are $800-1000 and more than capable of running the newest XCode versions for simple builds. And never did he say he had to buy new hardware or that he's using a PowerPC Mac. If he was, it's really time to upgrade. If the mac is Intel, can get 10.6 for $29 (just $34 in canada). Quite simple really.

Comment: If he had an intel mac he wouldn't need to upgrade to 10.6 since most of them came with 10.6 installed. 10 to 1 he's running ppc like me. In any case I have solved the problem.