# Question iOS SDK 4.0

Tags: xcode, ios, sdk

I am trying to locate IOS SDK 4.0. But I'm unable to find it. I'm currently running v10.5.6 osx and I'm unable to install the xcode iOS 4.2 cause it says I require 10.6.

Will iOS SDK 4.0 work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS SDK 4.0+ **requires** Snow Leopard / Mac OS 10.6+.

> **What are the system requirements for the iOS SDK?**
>
> To develop with iOS SDK and participate in the iOS Deeloper Program you must have an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Refer to the iOS SDK Read Me document for full details on system requirements. You must be registered as an Apple Developer in order to access the iOS SDK and iOS SDK Read Me document.

---

> **Compatibility:** Xcode 3.2 requires an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard version 10.6.4 or later. Note: some distributions of Xcode do not include the iOS SDKs; you can verify their presence in the Installer’s “Custom Install” pane.

Taken from [About Xcode and IOS SDK](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_sdk_4.2__final/readme_xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_4.2.pdf)

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain the reason for the down-vote? This info was take form Apple, so I don't see how it could possibly be  incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot install it on anything under 10.6: [How to install iphone sdk 4 on Mac OSX 10.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500722/how-to-install-iphone-sdk-4-on-mac-osx-10-5-8)